# What is the difference between normal and perpendicular?

Tags: geometry, terminology

What is the difference when a line is said to be normal to another and a line is said to be perpendicular to other?

Comment: None that I am aware of.

Comment: Nothing at all. "Normal" happens to be a more archaic way of saying "perpendicular".

Comment: semirelated: http://mathoverflow.net/a/7392/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are different kind of contexts you use term *normal* in mathematics. You often use *perpendicular* in case of two or three dimensional geometry, and in hi-dimensional spaces (e.g. infinite-dimensional) a term *orthogonal* is more common. On the other hand in the context of vectors, *normal* usually means also that the vector is of unit length, however this is not a must (but it is for example if you speak about orthonormal base).

There is yet another related meaning in computer graphics, where *normal* is the direction which you would use to reflect the light. This can be a vector perpendicular to rendered face, but for nice effects you use one perpendicular to the original surface, not its approximation. Also, there is [bump mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_mapping) technique that lets you change the normal vectors and achieve look of some kind of wrinkles and bumps.

Finally, e.g. in topology or group theory term *normal* means something completely different, however, I will leave those and others out as I suspect this was not the scope of your question. Hope this helps ;-)

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between saying two lines are perpendicular and that one line is normal to another line. It is literally a synonymous term, like saying that you take the product of two numbers or you multiply two numbers.

Comment: There is some difference in usage. It would be unusual to write that two lines are normal.

Comment: And perpendicular is less judgemental...

Answer (score 1):

Even I agree to the above contexts. Normal is more relevant to 3-D(Line and Surface) and perpendicular to 2-D(Line and Line = One Plane).

This is correct when we do say normal to surface and perpendicular to the line.

Answer (score 0):

Normal is 90 degree to a surface but perpendicular is 90 degree to a line

Answer (score -1):

A normal is an object such as a line or vector that is perpendicular to a given object. For example, in the two-dimensional case, the normal line to a curve at a given point is the line perpendicular to the tangent line to the curve at the point.

Answer (score -2):

If normal is 90 degree to the surface, that means normal is used in 3D. Perpendicular in that case is more in 2D referring two same entities (line-line) with 90 degree angle between them. Normal in this case could refer 2 different entities (line-surface) making this term valid for 3D case (I definitely remember hearing term "line normal to surface", rather then "line perpendicular to the surface") - line and surface makes 3D case; line and line is one plane - 2D. This I just figured out from one of the answers here which made most sense for me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please don't post inflammatory things like this.